# Return to form if all fields are not completed

Tags: javascript, forms, return

My apologies if the following is unclear - I am a baby in the javascript world and learning everyday!

When clicking submit, the javascript runs a to verify that all required fields are filled in. If the fields are filled in, the javascript then opens an email and attaches the form. I am having issues if all of the forms are not filled out. An alert pops up telling them what fields are not filled in and then continues to attach the form to an email. How can I disrupt the javascript from attaching to the email and instead send the user back to the form to complete?

```js
var emptyFields = [];

for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++) {
    var f = this.getField(this.getNthFieldName(i));

    if (f.type != "button" && f.required) {
        if (
            (f.type == "text" && f.value == "") ||
            (f.type == "checkbox" && f.value == "Off")
        )
            emptyFields.push(f.name);
    }
}

if (emptyFields.length > 0) {
    app.alert(
        "Error! You must fill in the following fields:\n" +
            emptyFields.join("\n")
    );
    return;
}
```

I have tried entering return, return; break, and break; at the end of the alert without success. The javascript still continues to attach the form to an email.

Comment: Alerts are a poor way to provide feedback. They require dismissal by the user and don't indicate field location, which is an accessibility problem. Please do some research into modern form validation for ideas. Often, simple [HTML element validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation#using_built-in_form_validation) is adequate.

Comment: The short answer to your actual question is that any JavaScript form validation should prevent form submission and only submit if the form validates. You see that in virtually any such strategy. Unfortunately you haven't shown us the context in which this code runs.